# autofill in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

so im making a report output so im trying to connect 2 table 
table 1:

```
+-------+------------+-------+
| House | HouseName  | Price |
+-------+------------+-------+
| A     | KAI        |    50 |
| B     | MAI        |    40 |
| C     | DAI        |    30 |
+-------+------------+-------+
```

table 2:

```
+-------+-------+------+
| House | Month | Days |
+-------+-------+------+
| A     | April |    5 |
| B     | April |    5 |
| A     | April |   20 |
| A     | May   |    5 |
+-------+-------+------+
```

the table i want (Picked by month) :

```
+-------------------------+------------+
| House(as in house name) | Total Days |
+-------------------------+------------+
| KAI                     |         25 |
| MAI                     |          5 |
| DAI                     |          0 |
+-------------------------+------------+
```

What I get is ( Month = 'April' ):

```
+-------------------------+------------+
| House(as in house name) | Total Days |
+-------------------------+------------+
| KAI                     |         25 |
| MAI                     |          5 |
+-------------------------+------------+
```

This is my code :

```
SELECT SUM(table2.Days) as Total Days, table1.HouseName as House
FROM table 2 INNER JOIN
     table 1
     ON table2.House = table1.House
WHERE table2.Month = 'April' GROUP BY table1.HouseName
```

i still cant get the output i wanted pls someone help me

Comment: wait why the table is like that ?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: `GROUP BY table1` makes no sense - you group by *columns* not table references

Comment: sorry im still new to sql so i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to turn your `inner join` to a `left join`, and accordingly move the condition on the `left join`ed table to the `on` clause of the join:

```
select t1.housename, coalesce(sum(t2.days), 0) total_days
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
    on t2.hourse = t1.house
    and t2.month = 'April'
group by t1.house, t1.housename
```

Note that I also added `t1.house` to the `group by` clause - in case two different houses have the same name, you probably want to count them separately.